# $f$ convex and concave, then $f=ax+b$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $f$ be a real function defined on some interval $I$.

Assuming that $f$ both convex and concave on $I$, i.e, for any $x,y\in I$ one has
$$f(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y)=\lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda)f(y),\, \, \lambda\in (0,1) .$$
I would like to show that $f$ is of the form 
$f=ax+b$ for some $a,b$.

I was able to prove it when $f$ is differentiable, using the relation 
$$f'(x)=f'(y).$$

Anyway, I was not able to provide a general proof (without assuming that $f$ is differentiable, and without assuming that $0\in I$).

Any answer will be will be appreciated.

Edit: It is little bit different from tte other question
[How to prove convex+concave=affine?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104810/how-to-prove-convexconcave-affine). Here $f$ is defined on some interval, so $o$ not necessary in the domain. Please remove the duplicate message if this possible

Comment: @Batman no, it is little bit different. Here $f$ is defined on some interval, so $o$ not necessary in the domain. Please remove the duplicate message if this possible.

Comment: It doesn't make a difference if $0$ is in the domain or not -- you can shift to make that true.

Comment: @Batman can you show me how there is no difference. Thanks

Comment: Batman's right.

Comment: @Mathemagician1234 can you explain?  Thanks

Comment: Say $c$ is the center of the interval $I$. Then, consider $g:I-c \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $g(x)=f(x-c)$, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x<y$ be in $I$. Then for $z=\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y\in [x,y]$,
$$f(z)=f(\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y)=\lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda)f(y)=\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}(z-x)+f(x)$$
Hence, $f(z)=az+b$ for some $a,b$ on every closed interval in $I$. Every interval can be expressed as the limit of a non-decreasing sequence of closed intervals $(I_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, and since $f\rvert I_n$ must coincide with $f\rvert I_{n+1}$ on $I_n$, we find that $f$ extends to a linear function $az+b$ on all of $I$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a fixed point $c \in I$. We have
$$\dfrac{f(c+\lambda(x-c))-f(c)}{\lambda(x-c)} = \dfrac{\lambda(f(x)-f(c))}{\lambda(x-c)}$$
Hence,
$$f'(c)=\lim_{\lambda \to 0}\dfrac{f(c+\lambda(x-c))-f(c)}{\lambda(x-c)} = \lim_{\lambda \to 0} \dfrac{\lambda(f(x)-f(c))}{\lambda(x-c)} = \dfrac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}$$
Hence, for all $x \in I$, we have
$$f(x) = f(c) + (x-c)f'(c)$$

Comment: Are you assuming that $f$ is differentiable? thanks.

Comment: @JohnJohn No. We infact prove that $f$ is differentiable, if $f(\lambda x+(1-\lambda )y) = \lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda)f(y)$

Comment: I will note that such functions are only provably differentiable Lebesgue-a.e. If memory serves, the set of non-differentiable points may be countable (but no larger)

Comment: I don’t see anything guaranteeing the existence of a fixed point (in fact, there is none in the case of $f(x)=x+b$ with $b\neq 0$)

Comment: @Jacob I guess he only means fixed choice of a point instead of fixed point. You can replace it by a sentence like "Let $c \in I$ be arbitrary".