# Find all continuous functions that satisfy the Jensen inequality(?) $f(\frac{x+y}{2})=\frac{f(x)+f(y)}{2}$

Tags: continuity, functional-equations

Find all continuous functions that satisfy the Jensen inequality(I don't know why the problems states ''inequality'') $$f(\frac{x+y}{2})=\frac{f(x)+f(y)}{2}$$

I've checked around stackexchange and google a bit, but none of the questions related to this problem gave me any hints on what I should do. The expression ''find all continuous functions'' confuses me. Am I supposed to determine some kind of a property that applies to all continuous functions that satisfy the property above or?
Likewise there is a problem asking to find all continuous functions that satisfy$$f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$$
I'm sorry if this is a duplicate question, but even after reading all of those answers I've failed to find an adequate one. Also, another problem is that I'm not allowed to use derivations, and hence anything more complex than that.

Comment: what is with $$y=x$$?

Comment: The Jensen inequality appears when you change $=$ into $\leq$, and once you've done that, it is true for all convex functions. I agree that the wording is a bit unfortunate, but the problem itself seems clear enough.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner what do you mean, what is with?

Comment: with this function, i think it will fulfill your equation

Comment: @Arthur I'm supposed to prove this with the knowledge I acquired at the university, and we haven't officially defined or even mentioned what convex functions are..

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner that is true, but I'm supposed to find ALL continuous function that satisfy the expression. That's what bugs me..

Comment: i think all linear functions satisfy your condition

Comment: The equality case in Jensen's inequality holds for both convex and concave functions. And a function both convex and concave can be shown to be of the form $y=ax+b$. See [convex+concave=affine](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104810/how-to-prove-convexconcave-affine) and its linked posts for more.

Comment: Some related posts: [How to show that $f$ is a straight line if $f(\frac{x+y}{2})=\frac{f(x)+f(y)}{2}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1646324) and [Function that is both midpoint convex and concave](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1850101).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first question is actually similar to the second question $$f\left(\frac{x+y}{2} \right)=\frac{f(x)+f(y)}{2}$$
Then we set $f(x)-f(0)=g(x)$. Note that $g(x)$ is also a solution to the functional equation. Now, let $x=2a, y=0$. Then notice $$2g(a)=g(2a) \implies g(a)=2g\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)$$ 
So $$g(x)+g(y)=2g\left(\frac{x+y}{2} \right)=g(x+y)$$
So the solutions to the first question are functions that satisfy the second question, plus some arbitrary constant $c$.

The second question is called the Cauchy Functional Equation, answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/356645/i-need-to-find-all-functions-f-mathbb-r-rightarrow-mathbb-r-which-are-contious).

Comment: Thanks for your answer!I understand the first part, but I've previously visited the link you suggested, but have failed to find an answer to ''all continuous functions satisfying the Cauchy Functional Equation''.

Comment: @DomoB  Editted.